# Records by matching and non-matching DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Please help me figure out the below logic. When B.DateTime matches E.DateTime then get E.Location. When B.DateTime <> E.DateTime, then get E.Location from the previous/earlier E.DateTime. Please include WHERE Location in ('City A','City B','City C','City E','City F','City G','City X','City Y'). I will be grateful to you. Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8eb014/1

```
Base table as B
Id   DateTime
201  2015-05-03 08:01
301  2015-05-03 08:20
401  2015-05-03 08:40

Extract Table as E
Id   DateTime            Location
201  2015-05-03 07:50    City A
201  2015-05-03 08:01    City B
201  2015-05-03 08:50    City C
301  2015-05-03 07:15    City E
301  2015-05-03 08:01    City F
301  2015-05-03 08:20    City G
401  2015-05-03 07:15    City X
401  2015-05-03 08:55    City Y

Desired Result:
Location  Id    DateTime
City B    201   2015-05-03 08:01
City G    301   2015-05-03 08:20
City X    401   2015-05-03 07:15
```

I tried the below code on sqlfiddle but it is having trouble executing:

```
select B.id, coalesce(E.Location,F.Location),coalesce(E.DateTime,F.DateTime)
from Base B
inner join Extract E
on B.id = E.id
and B.DateTime = E.DateTime
and E.Location in ('City A','City B','City C','City E','City F','City G','City X','City Y')
left join Extract F
on B.id = F.id
and F.DateTime < B.DateTime
and F.Location in ('City A','City B','City C','City E','City F','City G','City X','City Y')
```

When I run this logic with my actual data, I get the below result.

```
Location  Id    DateTime
City B    201   2015-05-03 08:01
City G    301   2015-05-03 08:20
```

Id 401 gets missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will order by first matching dates and then by date:

```
select B.id, ca.dt, ca.location
from B
cross apply(select top 1 location, dt
            from E 
            where B.id = E.id 
            order by case when B.dt = E.dt then 1 else 0 end desc,
                     E.dt)ca
```

Comment: That didn't give me the right time for id 401. It have me 8:40 instead of 7:15. But, Locations were right.

Comment: @sky_limit, just change select date from cross apply block... I have edited answer.

Comment: Sorry about that...got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query. You are using inner join on B and E which is filtering out 401 on datetime field as e does not have it.

```
select distinct b.id,coalesce(e.location,a.location) ,coalesce(e.datetime,a.dt)
from base b
left outer join extract e 
on b.id = e.id
and b.datetime = e.datetime
and E.Location in ('City A','City B','City C','City E','City F','City G','City X','City Y')
inner join 
(
select b2.id,f.location,max(f.datetime) as dt from base b2 join extract f on b2.id = f.id and b2.datetime <> f.datetime
where f.datetime < b2.datetime
group by b2.id,f.location 
) a
on b.id = a.id
```

Comment: Gaurav! Even your code worked but Giorgi had it first. I am trying to get my actual data to work with Giorgi or your code. Thanks all.

Comment: Yeah before edit Giorgi's code was not working as mentioned in comment by you also. :)

Comment: It was my mistake in editing the select statement. Isn't his code so simple to use? I appreciate the way you have coded as well. Thanks for it.